# R: Training and Test Set take on different values for Categorical Explanatory Variable: Logistic Regression

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I'm trying to predict the class a genetic variant belongs to.  My dataframe is called Genetic in my code. I split my dataframe into training and testing data set as so:

```
set.seed(1)
train=sample(54248,27124)
test=-train
Genetictrain=Genetic[train,]
Genetictest=Genetic[test,]
```

The problem is that one of my explanatory variables (which is categorical, one of the columns of the data-frame) takes on different values in the training set (Genetictrain) and the testing set (Genetictest).  The explanatory variable is called Genetic$Consequence.  The levels of Genetic$Consequence are:

```
 [1] "3_prime_UTR_variant"                                           
 [2] "5_prime_UTR_variant"                                           
 [3] "downstream_gene_variant"                                       
 [4] "frameshift_variant"                                            
 [5] "frameshift_variant&splice_region_variant"                      
 [6] "frameshift_variant&start_lost"                                 
 [7] "frameshift_variant&start_lost&start_retained_variant"          
 [8] "frameshift_variant&stop_lost"                                  
 [9] "frameshift_variant&stop_retained_variant"                      
[10] "inframe_deletion"                                              
[11] "inframe_deletion&splice_region_variant"                        
[12] "inframe_insertion"                                             
[13] "inframe_insertion&splice_region_variant"                       
[14] "intergenic_variant"                                            
[15] "intron_variant"                                                
[16] "intron_variant&non_coding_transcript_variant"                  
[17] "missense_variant"                                              
[18] "missense_variant&splice_region_variant"                        
[19] "protein_altering_variant"                                      
[20] "splice_acceptor_variant"                                       
[21] "splice_acceptor_variant&coding_sequence_variant"               
[22] 
"splice_acceptor_variant&coding_sequence_variant&intron_variant"
[23] "splice_acceptor_variant&intron_variant"                        
[24] "splice_donor_variant"                                          
[25] "splice_donor_variant&coding_sequence_variant"                  
[26] "splice_donor_variant&coding_sequence_variant&intron_variant"   
[27] "splice_donor_variant&intron_variant"                           
[28] "splice_region_variant&3_prime_UTR_variant"                     
[29] "splice_region_variant&5_prime_UTR_variant"                     
[30] "splice_region_variant&coding_sequence_variant&intron_variant"  
[31] "splice_region_variant&intron_variant"                          
[32] "splice_region_variant&synonymous_variant"                      
[33] "start_lost"                                                    
[34] "start_lost&5_prime_UTR_variant"                                
[35] "start_lost&splice_region_variant"                              
[36] "stop_gained"                                                   
[37] "stop_gained&frameshift_variant"                                
[38] "stop_gained&inframe_deletion"                                  
[39] "stop_gained&inframe_insertion"                                 
[40] "stop_gained&protein_altering_variant"                          
[41] "stop_gained&splice_region_variant"                             
[42] "stop_lost"                                                     
[43] "stop_lost&3_prime_UTR_variant"                                 
[44] "stop_retained_variant"                                         
[45] "stop_retained_variant&3_prime_UTR_variant"                     
[46] "synonymous_variant"   
[47] "TF_binding_site_variant"                                       
[48] "upstream_gene_variant"
```

However: When I run logistic regression on the training data (Genetictrain), I get the error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor Consequence has new levels frameshift_variant&stop_retained_variant, protein_altering_variant, splice_acceptor_variant&coding_sequence_variant, start_lost&splice_region_variant, stop_retained_variant&3_prime_UTR_variant
```

My code for the logistic regression was:

```
Logisticfit=glm(CLASS~AF_TGP + Consequence + CHROM + AF_ESP+STRAND + AF_EXAC + CADD_RAW + LoFtool + CADD_PHRED,data=Genetictrain,family="binomial")
LogisticProb=predict(Logisticfit,Genetictest,type="response")
```

The error results (running the code using the predict function above) because the training set, Genetictrain does not have any occurrences of protein altering variant for Consequence, but Genetictest does have an occurrence of protein altering variant for Consequence:

```
which(Genetictrain$Consequence=="protein_altering_variant")
integer(0)
 which(Genetictest$Consequence=="protein_altering_variant")
[1] 10720
```

Same for the other values which the error brings up.

Is there any way to circumvent this so I can run the predict function without receiving an error (note my explanatory variables are both categorical and continuous and I'm trying to predict CLASS which is binary 0 or 1)? Consequence is an important explanatory variable for me to keep so I don't want to delete it.
Thank you!

Comment: can u post sample data and `str(data)` please, also what is your target variable?

Comment: Response variable is CLASS.  dataset is from kaggle. 
 I can post how I prepocessed data set after loading csv file into . https://www.kaggle.com/kevinarvai/clinvar-conflicting

Answer (score 1):

Just now checked Your data frame.Problem raised with the data set **mismatch**

train data set and test data set is not having the same information in `Genetic$consequence` .

Check the below code:

```
data.frame(table(Genetic$Consequence))%>%setNames(.,c("Consequnce","Freq"))%>%arrange(Freq)
```

**output:**

```
                                                       Consequnce  Freq
1            frameshift_variant&start_lost&start_retained_variant     1
2                        frameshift_variant&stop_retained_variant     1
3                         inframe_insertion&splice_region_variant     1
4                    intron_variant&non_coding_transcript_variant     1
5    splice_region_variant&coding_sequence_variant&intron_variant     1
6                                  start_lost&5_prime_UTR_variant     1
7                                    stop_gained&inframe_deletion     1
8                                   stop_gained&inframe_insertion     1
9                            stop_gained&protein_altering_variant     1
```

There is 9 types of consequence of frequency as 1 means if u split the data frame that will go in train or test data set.

**Example**
Say example as "frameshift_variant&start_lost&start_retained_variant" is with one row only in Genericdata$consequence so when u divide the data frame it will go in train or test data set. if that row in train data set then for the test data set has no rows in it. For that only it returns error.

solution:
try to get more variables for the frequency with 1 (means there is only one row exists,so need at least 2 to use in one train and one in test data set )
 or
U can subset the data set like Frequency with low numbers , so that u can get information easily in both train  and test data sets.

Comment: can I just delete the rows corresponding to these frequencies of 1 before splitting the data frame into train or test data set or is this not good practice?

Comment: yes u may subset the data set before splitting and try once. if still not works please post error here

Comment: **before splitting please careful with the class of Genetic$Consequence , it has to be in factor format and also splitting good methods `ind<-sample(2,nrow(Genetic),replace = T,prob=c(0.7,0.3))
Genetictrain<-Genetic[ind==1,]
Genetictest<-Genetic[ind==2,] `**